Size Features for variable fonts have non consistent output
Edit: Thinking about it, I opened a bug report:
https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/291
TeXlive 2024, up-to-date, on Linux machine
I'm experimenting with size features according to the fontspec manual, section 5, p. 24. The output for variable fonts is unexpected.
This first MWE provides the expected output:
\DocumentMetadata{lang=de}
\documentclass[parskip=half, ngerman, fontsize=12pt, paper=A5, DIV=25]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont{Alegreya Sans Regular}[
Renderer = HarfBuzz,
SizeFeatures = {
  {Size = -11, OpticalSize = 16, Color=AA0000},
  {Size=11-13, OpticalSize=36, Color=00AA00},    
  {Size=13-, OpticalSize=72, Color=0000AA}},
BoldFont=Alegreya Sans Bold,
ItalicFont=Alegreya Sans Italic,
BoldItalicFont=Alegreya Sans BoldItalic,
BoldFeatures = {
  SizeFeatures = {
  {Size = -11, OpticalSize = 16, Color=AA0000},
  {Size=11-13, OpticalSize=36, Color=00AA00},    
  {Size=13-, OpticalSize=72, Color=0000AA}},
  }
    ]

% \setsansfont{FrauncesVariable.ttf}[
% %Renderer = HarfBuzz,
% SizeFeatures = {
%   {Size = -11, OpticalSize = 16, Color=AA0000},
%   {Size=11-13, OpticalSize=36, Color=00AA00},    
%   {Size=13-, OpticalSize=72, Color=0000AA}},
% BoldFont = *,
% ItalicFont = FrauncesItalicVariable.ttf,
% BoldItalicFont = FrauncesItalicVariable.ttf, 
% UprightFeatures = {Weight = 300},
% ItalicFeatures = {Weight = 300},
% BoldFeatures = {Weight = 600},
% BoldItalicFeatures = {Weight = 600},
% ]

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\title{Alegreya Sans}

\newcommand{\blindsatz}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
  adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque
  pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec
  ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo,}



\begin{document}
\maketitle{}
    
1234567890

\blindsatz{}\footnote{\blindsatz{}}

\emph{\blindsatz{} 1234567890}

\textbf{\blindsatz{}}

\textbf{\emph{\blindsatz{}}}

\end{document}
% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: Lua-dev
% End:

The result:

But if I comment out Alegreya and comment in FrauncesVariable, the output is different. The italic version is green, despite there is no corresponding size feature command. I tried with another variable font (RobotoFlex) with the same result. The Fraunces font is used in luaotfload-latex manual on p. 15., I got the ttf from google fonts.

This seems as bug of fontspec or luaotfload to me. It does not depend on Renderer = HarfBuzz. Is it a bug or do I misunderstand something?
